# XmlException when loading an XML file with certain characters

Tags: c#, xml, exception, character-encoding, xmldocument

I need to use the `XmlDocument` class to load an XML file:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filename);
```

Unfortunately I get an `XmlException` when in my XML there are specifc characters that I use to rappresent my data, in particular I have a node like the following:

```
<rect data="string with invalid characters: † ¶"/>
```

So, the forbidden characters are: `†` and `¶`.

How can I load the file without exceptions and leaving these characters in my XML file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to replace those characters with a numerical character reference. Similar to how you replace > and < with & gt; and & lt;, you would replace those characters with something like & #931; or whatever references those specific characters.

edit: I had to add a space after the & to avoid the editor actually picking up and interpreting the character. Just remove the space in use - you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have no control over the source of the XML and just need to read all of the values in to a database or something, you could use an XmlTextReader to read through the xml line by line, stop on the element you know may contain bad data, and read the chars of that element. I've had to do this in the past. Something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xtr = new XmlTextReader("");
        xtr.Normalization = false;

        while (xtr.Read())
        {
            if(xtr.IsStartElement("Row")) // My xml doc contains many row elements
            {
                var fields = new string[6];
                while(xtr.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // I know my xml only has six child elements per row
                    {
                        while(!xtr.IsStartElement())
                        {
                            xtr.Read(); // We're not interested in hitting the end elements
                        }

                        if(i == 1) // I know my special characters are in the second child element of my row
                        {
                            var charBuff = new char[255];
                            xtr.ReadChars(charBuff, 0, 255); // I know there will be a maximum of 255 characters

                            fields[i] = new string(charBuff);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fields[i] = xtr.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```